# The instance member 'params' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class LevelUp extends GetxController {
  Map<String, String> params = Get.arguments;

  var myTest = params.[comLevel];
}
```

> Error report--"The instance member 'params' can't be accessed in an initializer."

I am new to programming and this is being called directly from a widget. I checked the LevelUp map and it has contents. The error occurs where I am trying to assign the param value to myTest. It doesn't matter if I put the key in quotes or provide an integer.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can't access `params` before you've initialized the object. To fix your example, move your `myTest` initialization into a constructor.

Also, I don't believe you should have a period before `[comLevel]`.

```
class LevelUp extends GetxController {
  Map<String, String> params = Get.arguments;
  String myTest;
  
  LevelUp() {
    myTest = params[comLevel];
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a mutability warning in a stateless widget when moving initialization to the constructor.

Comment: What about mixins?

Answer (score 66):

#### Null safety update:

**Use `late` keyword**: Dart 2.12 comes with `late` keyword which helps you do the lazy initialization which means until the field `bar` is used it would remain uninitialized.

```dart
class Test {
  int foo = 0;
  late int bar = foo; // No error
}
```

Comment: adding late keyword to lazy initialise helped me. thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 26):

Although this question has been answered for the OP's case, I want to offer a solution to those receiving this error in a `StatefulWidget` scenario.

Consider a situation where you would want to have a list of selectable items that dictate which category to display. In this case, the constructor might look something like this:

```dart
CategoryScrollView({
  this.categories,
  this.defaultSelection = 0,
});

final List<String> categories;
final int defaultSelection;
```

Note the property `defaultSelection` is responsible for specifying which category should be selected by default. You would probably also want to keep track of which category is selected after initialization, so I will create `selectedCategory`. I want to assign `selectedCategory` to `defaultSelection` so that the default selection takes effect. In `_CategoryScrollViewState`, you cannot do the following:

```dart
class _CategoryScrollViewState extends State<CategoryScrollView> {

  int selectedCategory = widget.defaultSelection; // ERROR

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The line, `int selectedCategory = widget.defaultSelection;` will not work because `defaultSelection` it hasn't been initialized yet (mentioned in other answer). Therefore, the error is raised:

> The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.

The solution is to assign `selectedCategory` to `defaultSelection` ***inside*** of the `initState` method, initializing it ***outside*** of the method:

```dart
class _CategoryScrollView extends State<CategoryScrollView> {

  int selectedCategory;

  void initState() {
    selectedCategory = widget.defaultSelection;
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

A simple example, where it shows how we can resolve the above issue,
Example: Create an instance of class B, and pass an instance of class A in the parameter of it

**WRONG(Compile time error of initializer):**

```
  final A _a = A();
  final B _b = B(_a);
```

shows error: The instance member '_a' can't be accessed in an initializer.

---

**Right:**

```
  final A _a = A();
  late final B _b;

  AppointmentRepository() {
    _b = B(_a);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use instance members as a initialization for a variable in a class. If you can make the member **static**, that is the simplest and safest way to solve the problem. It is introduced in Dart Document as well: [Link](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=implicit_this_reference_in_initializer#implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)

Solution:

```
class LevelUp extends GetxController {
  static Map<String, String> params = Get.arguments;

  var myTest = params.[comLevel];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#100% working solution
:
Juts place var `myTest = params.[comLevel];`
below your Build method.

eg.

```
class LevelUp extends GetxController {
   Map<String, String> params = Get.arguments;
    
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var myTest = params.[comLevel];
}
}
```

Comment: I told the same thing but got downvoted for God knows why. :D Look at all those answers. People like making things complicated.

Comment: I like this better than "late". I don't know the following: 1. how "late" works under the hood 2. what bugs/quirks it might create during runtime 3. how to debug it. I upvoted your answer also @zibidigonzales

Answer (score 2):

For me it happened Because i was trying to access a Property of a class instance  (Lets Say Class A ) And Use this property to initialize  Another Class (Class B)  , The Property Was Integer Number and Was Defined

However , Since i didn't Make an Object from "Class A" I can access those propertied Belong to it !
I tried to use this property inside the "Build" Method so that an object is "Created/Built" And it Worked !

Answer (score 1):

I also got the similar error.
And I found the solution as follows.

My first code:

```
final BuildContext mycontext = GlobalContextClass.navigatorKey.currentContext;
final PsValueHolder psValueHolder = Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(mycontext, listen: false);
```

Next is the code where the error is fixed:

```
final PsValueHolder psValueHolder = Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(GlobalContextClass.navigatorKey.currentContext, listen: false);
```

Instead of defining 2 variables in a row, I placed the first variable directly in the place of the 2nd variable.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is making your variable, a GetX parameter.

```
  int count_myProducts = cartItems.length; //The instance member 'cartItems' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)

  int get count_myProducts => cartItems.length;
```

see this video at 27:34
GetX State Management tutorial with Flutter
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnevdXDH25Q&ab_channel=CodeX

Answer (score 0):

Just carry

```
var myTest = params.[comLevel];
```

into Widget build{} below.

like this :

```
class LevelUp extends GetxController {
   Map<String, String> params = Get.arguments;
    
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     var myTest = params.[comLevel];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented and solve mine using late keyword for instance

```
late List<Widget> _pages = [];
```