# The instance member 'a' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Why we cannot put variable `a` into `myList` like this?

When I am doing this the compiler says
**The instance member 'a' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression** which is not clear for me.

If this then how can I able to get the data from `a` in method `age()`      ?

Can any body help me to understand what is going here??

```dart
class Test {
  int a = 5;

  List<int> all = [a];

  int age() {
    int b = a * 5;
    return b;
  }
}
```

But when I copy myList and paste in the constructor like this it is working fine. what is the reason behind this?

```dart
class Test {
 int a = 5;

 Test() {
   List<int> myList = [a];
 }

 int age() {
   int b = a * 5;
   return b;
 }
}
```

I found one post about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542776/the-instance-member-params-cant-be-accessed-in-an-initializer) but it was not clear what is the reason behind this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/.  When you initialize inline in the class definition, it's initialized early, before `this` exists.  Consequently, it cannot depend on other instance members.

Comment: Yes, some how it does. thanks a lot