# The instance member 'mail' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to use the indexOf method in Dart and this error occurs. I have simply used two strings and thats it.

[image: Screen Shot of the issue]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access instance fields before you initialized the object, in this case `_MyHomePageState`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/63542846/9479695

I think in your case you want to use the initState Method for your Stateful Widget.
See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableTextState/initState.html

Comment: Thank you! I shall surely look into it and post the progress.